# How to conditionally ignore error encountered by roles

Tags: ansible

In the following playbook , I am trying to ignore all the errors encountered during the execution of role1 and role2 only when value of "`a`" is 50, in rest condition do not ignore error, Is it possible ?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    a:10

  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
  ignore_errors: True
```

Above code, work fine. It ignores the error seen by these roles. By how to put `ignore_Errors` in condition `a == 50` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `ignore_errors` value to the result of `a == 50`:

```
ignore_errors: "{{ a == 50 }}"
```

Unless you know `a` is definitely an integer it's probably a string though so you should quote the value it's being compared against:

```
ignore_errors: "{{ a == '50' }}"
```

Comment: You could also just use `"{{ a|int == 50 }}"` if you aren't sure whether `a` is a string or integer